# How to get the contents of a specific page from controller in CodeIgniter?

Tags: php, codeigniter

I want to create a dynamic page by using CodeIgniter Framework. When I click the link, it creates a link depends on id. But didn't show any contents in the page. Showed "Object not found." How can I connect controller and view here?

$route['report/:any/:num'] = "home/reportcard";

Here is my code:

1. controller:

   public function index(){

   ```
   $this->load->model("item_model");
   $data['records'] = $this->item_model->getAllItems();
   $this->load->view('home',$data);
   }

   function reportcard(){
       $this->load->view('main');  
   }
   ```
2. view where created a link depends on id:

   ```
   <div class="row">
                       <ul class="home-grid">
                           <?php foreach ($query->result() as $row): ?>
                           <li>
                               <a  href="<?php echo base_url() ?>report/<?=$row->item ?>/<?=$row->id ?>" class="btn btn-lg btn-warning view-report"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-list-alt"></span> <br/>
                               <?=$row->item ?><br/>
                                <small>Click here for see report</small>
                               </a>
                           </li>
                           <?php endforeach; ?>
                       </ul>
    </div>
   ```

For checking purpose in my main.php view, I just added "Hello World". But it didn't show anything. How can I get the view?

Comment: data available in view as `$record` variable.So loop over `$record` in your view.

Answer (score 0):

https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/views.html
check the "creating loops" section

$data must be an array, this can then be accessed in your view like

```
foreach ($records as $record) :
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe better solution is creating `<form>` tag and submit anything you want from view.
Then in controller you can add this:
`$something = $this->input->post('something');` 
Check [codeigniter documentation](https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/input.html)

Answer (score 0):

Your reportcard function should be like this:

```
function reportcard($id){
    $data['report'] = $this->item_model->getReport($id);
    $this->load->view('main', $data);  
}
```

route should be like:

```
$route['report/:num'] = "home/reportcard/$1";
```

view should be like:

```
<div class="row">
                    <ul class="home-grid">
                        <?php foreach ($query->result() as $row): ?>
                        <li>
                            <a  href="<?php echo base_url() ?>report/<?=$row->id ?>" class="btn btn-lg btn-warning view-report"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-list-alt"></span> <br/>
                            <?=$row->item ?><br/>
                             <small>Click here for see report</small>
                            </a>
                        </li>
                        <?php endforeach; ?>
                    </ul>
 </div>
```

and then in main view you can access data like:

```
print_r($report);
```

Comment: Here is my getReport function. It didn't show any data. Again show error. I don't understand what is the problem here.  

function getReport($id){
            $this->load->database();
            $this->db->where('id_user', '1');

            return $this->db->get('users')->row();
    }